# Should I use express-jwt or passport-jwt for securing an Express/Angular app?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, express-jwt, passport-jwt

I'm trying to figure out passport. I want to secure an API-based frontend (Angular).

I assume that means I can't use `passport-local`, and that I must use `passport-http` to get the username/password, and then `passport-jwt` to perform JWT signing and verification. Correct?

However then it gets confusing, because there is an even more popular package called `express-jwt`. Are they different? I'm not sure which is used for what purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very similar. But passport is unmaintained, there are bugs in many of its plugins ("strategies"), and dozens of PRs that will never get merged.

So I went with `express-jwt`, which is maintained.